# PCA proof, trace move

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, trace, orthonormal

In the PCA proof, I see this move:
[image]

What is the "trace" algebra/rule that allow this trace-move?

Comment: $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$.

Comment: First treat the scalar value as a $1\times 1$ matrix, whose trace is the scalar value itself. Then apply the trace rule suggested by Zhanxiong

Comment: Thank you, yes, I guess that you can always wrap a 1x1 matrix with trace(), right?